# View transition on scroll view

Tags: swift, transition

I have set up a view containing a scrollview, I am attempting to allow the user to close the view by swiping down on the scroll view.

I have used the code below which as you can see dismisses the view controller when the scrollview y position is greater than -150.

When it reaches that point the view disappears, but ideally what I would like is for the view to continue moving downwards until it is out of view.

How would I go about this?

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0) {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = abs(scrollView.contentOffset.y) * 2
    }
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -150) {
        dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's much better to add a constraint and on swipe down change constraint value to -ve and animate it using UIViewAnimation

Comment: the view is presented modally, is it possible to add a constraint in this scenario?

Comment: Try adding the controller as a ChildViewController to the MainController then